# further simplify integral trigonometric identites

Tags: calculus

can't seem to use double-angle identities, or half angle identities, unless im missing something from calculus 2, this should be an easy thing to solve in calc 3 but can't seem to scratch it.

$$\int\sqrt{2-2\sin{5t}\sin{t}-2\cos{5t}\cos{t}} \, dt$$

Comment: Remember from trigonometry that $\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta = \cos(\alpha+\beta)$. So $\cos(5t)\cos t+\sin(5t)\sin t = \cos(5t-t) = \cos(4t)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you mean $\cos (\alpha - \beta)$

Comment: ok thanks I see it now

Comment: @tomi : Correct.  I'm sorry about any inconvenience thus occasioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this identity (compund angle formula):

$\cos(A-B)=\cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B$

In your case $A=5t$ and $B=t$

Answer (score 2):

Remember the angle-addition formula for cosine:
$$ \cos{a-b} = \cos{a}\cos{b}+\sin{a}\sin{b}. $$
Applying this, we have
$$ \int \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-\cos{4t}} \, dt $$
Now, recall the double-angle formulae for cosine:
$$ \cos{2a} = \cos^2{a}-\sin^2{a} = 2\cos^2{a}-1 = 1-2\sin^2{a}, $$
so
$$ 1-\cos{2a} = 2\sin^2{a}. $$
Using this (and assuming that the positive root is taken) gives
$$ \int \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-\cos{4t}} \, dt = \int \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2\sin^2{2t}} \, dt = 2\int \sin{2t} \, dt = -\cos{2t} + C $$

Comment: Careful - it's $4t$ etc.

Comment: D'oh, of course... did all the hard bits correctly. Better?